# pattern match component 'x' is constrained to be isInstanceOf[List[Any]] - but can't treat 'x' as that type on RHS

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

To get familiar with Scala lists I decided to implement `flatten`, which would take a list like:  `List(List(2,4), 22, List(1))` to `List(2, 4, 22, 1)`.

When I attempted to run the code below

```
def flatify(xs: List[Any]) : List[Any] = {
  xs match {
    case Nil=> {
      Nil
    }
    case x::rest if x.isInstanceOf[List[Any]] => {
      flatify(x):: flatify(rest)   // bad line
    }
    case x::rest => {
      x:: flatify(rest)
    }
    case _ => {
      throw new IllegalStateException("cant match")
    }
  }
}

var list = List(List(4, 5), 9, 10, List(1, 2))
flatify(list)
```

The compiler complained about the line commented as '// bad line', saying:

```
Error:(84, 17) type mismatch;
     found   : Any
     required: List[Any]
            flatify(x):: flatify(rest)
                    ^
```

This strikes me as very odd, since my guard condition explicitly 
requires `x` to be `isInstanceOf[List[Any]]`.   I understand that 
`Any` is a superclass of `List[Any]` but I would have thought that
once the compiler gets to the right hand side of the expression

```
flatify(x) :: flatify(rest)
```

it would accept that `x` is a `List[Any]`.

I'm sure my implementation might have other problems as I have not
fully debugged it yet, but before I moved on I wanted to try to 
understand what the Scala compiler was up to here.  Any tips or 
pointers are gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're matching on a `List[Any]`, so when you have

```
case x :: tail if(x.isInstanceOf[List[Any]]) => x ...
     ^             ^                            ^
    Any        true, but the type of       Still Any
               x is already determined
```

`x` is `Any` and `tail` is `List[Any]`. The `if` condition does nothing change the type of `x`, even if you can test that `x.isInstanceOf[List[Any]]`, `x` is still `Any`. You need to match on the type, itself.

```
def flatify(xs: List[Any]) : List[Any] = {
    xs match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case (x: List[Any]) :: rest => flatify(x) ::: flatify(rest)
      case x :: rest => x :: flatify(rest)
      case _ =>  throw new IllegalStateException("cant match")
    }
  }
```

Furthermore, there is another bug. Given `x` correctly matched as `List[Any]`, the following `flatify(x) :: flatify(rest)` will place a `List[Any]` at the head of a `List[Any]`, and therefore does no flattening at all. So I changed it to `:::`.

```
scala> flatify(List(1,2,3,List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9)))
res1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: spot-on helpful answer from both you and sepp2k..   But since you even fixed my dumb bug with :::  I'll accept yours, but thanks to you both !

Answer (score 3):

Scala's type system (just like Java's) does not change the type of a variable inside an if, even if the if condition was `isInstanceOf`. There are two ways to make your code work:

The Java way would be to use a cast to tell Scala that it's okay to use x as a list after you checked that it is indeed a list using `isInstanceOf`.

The Scala way is to just not use `isInstanceOf` at all, but rather use `x : List[Any]` in your pattern, which *does* make the static type of `x` `List[Any]`, so `x` can be used as a list without a cast.